# Does using a lock mitigate issues handled by the volatile keyword?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a `Foo` class that I think should **not** be thread-safe, yet I can't seem to reproduce the issue. One method it has is `update` which sets the current map from the parameter and mutate the old map. The other method is `read` which always gets a value from current map.

Please take a look at the test example. I have two threads, one which calls `update` and the other `read`. I'd expect `read` to sometimes read from an older version of `currMap` (because it's not `volatile`) which got mutated by `update`, and therefore return `-1`, yet it doesn't happen. Is this a coincidence or expected?

```java
  private static class Foo {
    Map<Integer, Integer> currMap;
    Object lock = new Object();

    Foo(Map<Integer, Integer> newMap) {
      currMap = newMap;
    }

    void update(Map<Integer, Integer> newMap) {
      synchronized (lock) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> oldMap = currMap;
        currMap = newMap;
        oldMap.remove(0);
      }
    }

    int read() {
      int val;
      synchronized (lock) {
        val = currMap.getOrDefault(0, -1);
      }
      return val;
    }
  }
  @Test
  public void testExample() throws InterruptedException {
    AtomicInteger readWrong = new AtomicInteger(0);
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(0, 0);
    Foo foo = new Foo(new HashMap<>(map));
    Thread updater = new Thread(() -> {
      while (readWrong.get() == 0) {
        foo.update(new HashMap<>(map));
      }
    });

    Thread reader = new Thread(() -> {
      while (readWrong.get() == 0) {
        if (foo.read() == -1) {
          readWrong.incrementAndGet();
        }
      }
    });

    updater.start();
    reader.start();

    updater.join();
    reader.join();

    assertTrue(readWrong.get() > 0);
  }
```

Comment: Your code, as written, is thread-safe. Using `synchronized` creates a _happens-before_ relationship, same as `volatile`. The former is simply more versatile because you can guard an entire block of code rather than just a single field. Since you synchronize on the same lock object when reading and writing the `currMap` field, that field is properly guarded. And the flow of your code is such that the `Map` _instance_ referenced by `currMap` is never accessed by multiple threads concurrently after the field has been assigned. Even after writing to the field, the old instance is simply [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] lost to the void, never to be accessed again by any thread, let alone the "reader" thread. And you always do `foo.update(new HashMap<>(map))`. That copies the original `map` instance, which has the `0 -> 0` entry. So, the map referenced by `currMap` can never _not_ have that entry. Given the fact the original `map` instance is never modified, and the call to `map.put(0, 0)` _happens-before_ both `reader.start()` and `writer.start()`, you can see why you never read the wrong value.

Comment: ...Specifically, When thread A _exits_ from a block that is synchronized on some Object, o; that  event "happens before" some other thread B subsequently enters a block that is `synchronized` on the same object, o. In more practical terms, it means that whatever thread A did before it released some lock is guaranteed to be visible to thread B after thread B subsequently acquires the same lock. That rule also works for `ReentrantLock` objects and other `Lock` objects.

Comment: In addition, if `currMap` _was_ `volatile` but the `synchronized` blocks were not present, it _would not_ be threadsafe, as the read of `currMap` could read a value that has not yet been updated, then calls to `oldMap.remove(0)` and `currMap.getOrDefault(0, -1)` could execute concurrently on the same instance of the `HashMap`. The `synchronized` blocks ensure that the update and read operations execute atomically.